# Get rid of Sleeveless Armor in X-COM on XBox-360

Tags: xbox-360, xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

as the title says, I am playing X-COM: Enemy Within on my XBox-360. Since this make it impossible to install Mods (like on the PC-Version), I can't use them to get rid of the sleeveless armor from the gene modded soldiers. Is there any way (a mod, patch, whatever), to get normal armor even for my gene modded soldiers? Or is there maybe a patch or DLC announced...?

Comment: Not an answer, perhaps, but the Armor Deco options (under "Customise" for each soldier) let you add some shoulders. It's not really sleeves, but it makes the armour look a little less silly.